# Return excel file from AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to return an excel file through Lambda. It succeeded, but the content is only the base64 encoded string of the file.

Here's the code:

```
const xl = require("excel4node")

module.exports.handler = async () => {
    var wb = new xl.Workbook()
    var ws = wb.addWorksheet('Sheet 1')
    const cols = [ "col1", "col2" ]
    cols.forEach((c,i) => { ws.cell(1, i+1).string(c) })
    const buffer = await wb.writeToBuffer()
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': "*",
            'Content-type' : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="test.xlsx"`,
        },
        isBase64Encoded: true,
        body: buffer.toString('base64')
    }
}
```

and [this is what's generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3FpQ.png)

I'm using Serverless framework, and I've set contentHandling config to CONVERT_TO_BINARY.

Many thanks,

Comment: Why not do something with the Excel doc in an AWS Lambda function. For example, you can easily code the Lambda function to store it in an Amazon S3 bucket or even email it as an attachment via SES. .

Comment: @smac2020 hi, thanks for the suggestion. I don't think this would fit my current usecase. This will be used for exporting dynamic data

Comment: Assuming you are using API Gateway, see [Return binary media from a Lambda proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html) and [Enabling binary support using the API Gateway console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html).

Comment: @jarmod I've followed the docs, unfortunately still same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved! after rereading @jarmod's answer above, turns out I had not set the API binary media type to '*/*'

added [apiGateWay.binaryMediaTypes](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#binary-media-types) in serverless config file and it worked